# Chrome/Firefox opens PDF in new tab and does not save it in headless mode (Selenium+Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have an issue with headless chrome when performing a test: a PDF file opens in a new tab when clicking on a button. If I run the test in NON-headless mode, all is fine. But when try to do the same in headless - file is not downloading.

```
options = ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
            options.add_argument('--test-type')
            options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
            options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
            options.add_argument('--verbose')
            options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
            options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
            options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
                "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                "download.default_directory": dwnld_path,
                "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                "download.directory_upgrade": True,
                "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
                "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
                "plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
            })
```

I also found that:

```
wd.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')

params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': dwnld_path}}
        command_result = wd.execute("send_command", params)
```

But it helps only if I get a request to download in headless mode, not if the file opens in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the url of the PDF file and download it with requests library, I think it will work.

Like this:

```
import urllib3
import PyPDF2
import certifi
import io

http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
pdf_url = "http:\\XXXXXX.pdf"
r3 = http.request('GET', pdf_url)
with io.BytesIO(r3.data) as open_pdf_file:
      read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)
      num_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
```

and then we need the second part of the code that you need to save pdf in a similar way

Comment: Unfortunately, no =\ File is displayed by JS, and when I try to get the file from URL using wget or urllib or requests it downloads the HTML source code with JS

example: my url is https://some.com/unique_file_if.pdf
page source code contains <html>blablabla<body><script>some js code</script></body></html>
if I press ctrl+s it downloads the file file_name.pdf.
if I use wget, urllib, requests it downloads the source code.

So, I need a kind of ctrl+s emulation... and I'd prefer to not use ActionChains... it's too "ducktapely" (=

Comment: Nono, no html file, just get the pdf_url from the html, please see my comment above edited.

Comment: in `read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open_pdf_file)` I get an error:      
`PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: EOF marker not found`